# Скрыть блок, который появляется по наведению

Tags: javascript, css

Всем доброго времени суток. 
[Есть такой вот код](http://codepen.io/pen/bdbWLb) при наведении на красный круг с вопросом всплывает подсказка.

```js
$(".close_help").click(function() {
  $('.interact').removeClass("interact");
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.promo_code__q').addClass('interact')
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.promo_code {
  position: relative;
}
.promo_code__q {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ed1f24;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.promo_code__q:hover .promo_code_help {
  background: green;
}
.interact:hover .promo_code_help {
  display: block;
}
.promo_code_help {
  position: absolute;
  left: 33px;
  top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.promo_code_help::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: -17px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ED1F24;
}
.title_promo_code_help {
  background-color: #ED1F24;
  width: 193px;
  height: 49px;
  padding: 14px 50px 20px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.close_help {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo_code">
  <span class="promo_code__label">Промо-код: 
      <span class="promo_code__q interact">?
           <div class="promo_code_help">
        <div class="title_promo_code_help">
          <p>Введите промокод на скидку, который у вас есть.</p>
          <span class="close_help">&times;</span>
</div>
</div>
</span>

</span>
<input type="text" class="promo_code__field" id="coupon" name="COUPON" value="" onchange="enterCoupon();submitForm();">
<button onclick="enterCoupon();submitForm();return false;" class="promo_code__btn">Применить</button>

</div>
```

Как по нажатию на крестик в подсказке, скрыть ее, но так что бы при повторном наведении на круг она появлялась снова?

Comment: Немного не по теме комментарий: а зачем? Зачем крестик, скрывающий всплывающую подсказку, которая сама убирается, когда её покидает курсор? Это немножко противоречит практике использования этих элементов. Обычно используют либо подсказку, которая убирается только по нажатию крестика (обычно она появляется только по клику), либо подсказку, которая исчезает сама при потере фокуса (такие подсказки появляются по наведению на элемент).

Comment: @fori1ton, на самом деле сейчас это довольно модная фича, когда можно разными способами сделать одно и тоже действие. Пусть это усложняет работу, зато на результате у каждого есть выбор как именно взаимодействовать с элементом

Comment: Используйте кнопку "вставить фрагмент" (Ctrl+M) для добавления кода. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на JSFiddle и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Один из вариантов](http://s.codepen.io/Melongeno/debug/pJzPVy?), мы добавлем доп. класс, у которого на `hover`, как раз стоит показать блок с подсказкой. При клике на иконку мы убираем этот класс => правило пропадает и блок скрывается. Затем снова добавляем этот же класс для дальнейшего использования ( `setInterval` для того что бы браузер успел принять правило и скрыть блок, можно сделать поменьше )
P.S использовать JQuery

Comment: Спасибо большое, я тоже начал подумывать над похожим вариантом :)

Answer (score 0):

С таким кодом - никак.
Там через CSS-свойство `:hover`, на него не дозволено повлиять как-либо, кроме движения мышы.
Будь там JS - сделать было бы легко, сколько раз я делал объекты нотификации самого разного вида, но не в этот раз.
И главное - зачем?
Сам смысл этой концепции не допускает "закрывающих крестиков". Нужны крестики - иди в JS.

Comment: Народ, если бы я знал зачем, макет такой прислали, вот и мучаюсь теперь, мозг ломаю. Тогда ваш вариант кода, ну или хотя бы идею как все это переделать?

Comment: Если есть возможность редактировать код, то запили на JS - там плёвое дело, [Just Fucking Google It](http://justfuckinggoogleit.ru).

Answer (score 0):

Если ничего не менять: http://jsfiddle.net/fbtbt7Lb/1/

```
$( ".interact" ).mouseout(function() { 
  $(".interact").css('pointer-events','auto');
  $(".promo_code_help").css('display','');
});

$(".close_help").click(function() {
  $(".interact").css('pointer-events','none');
  $(".promo_code_help").css('display','none');
});
```

Ну а по хорошему ввести доп. класс конечно.